# Python-solidity-parser failed to handle throw keyword

Tags: python, json, parsing, antlr, solidity

I tried to parse the following code using python-solidity-parser (https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13; 
contract someContract { 
      mapping(address => uint) balances; 
     
      function deposit() payable {
            balances[msg.sender] += msg.value; 
      } 
function withdrawOkayish(uint amount) { 
     if(balances[msg.sender] >= amount) { 
          balances[msg.sender] -= amount;    if(!msg.sender.send(amount)) { throw; } 
   } 
 } 
function withdrawBad2(uint amount) { 
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= amount) { 
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;   
    if(!msg.sender.call.gas(2500000).value(amount)()) { throw; } 
 } 
} 

}
```

It produces the following output

```
{'children': [{'name': 'solidity',
               'type': 'PragmaDirective',
               'value': '^0.4.13'},
              {'baseContracts': [],
               'kind': 'contract',
               'name': 'someContract',
               'subNodes': [{'initialValue': None,
                             'type': 'StateVariableDeclaration',
                             'variables': [{'expression': None,
                                            'isDeclaredConst': False,
                                            'isIndexed': False,
                                            'isStateVar': True,
                                            'name': 'balances',
                                            'type': 'VariableDeclaration',
                                            'typeName': {'keyType': {'name': 'address',
                                                                     'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'},
                                                         'type': 'Mapping',
                                                         'valueType': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                       'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}},
                                            'visibility': 'default'}]},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                       'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                              'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                       'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                        'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                        'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                              'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                     'operator': '+=',
                                                                     'right': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                               'memberName': 'value',
                                                                               'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                     'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'ExpressionStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'deposit',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': 'payable',
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'FalseBody': None,
                                                      'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                           'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                     'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                     'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                           'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                                                  'operator': '-=',
                                                                                                  'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                  'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'ExpressionStatement'},
                                                                                  {'FalseBody': None,
                                                                                   'TrueBody': {'statements': [';'],
                                                                                                'type': 'Block'},
                                                                                   'condition': {'isPrefix': True,
                                                                                                 'operator': '!',
                                                                                                 'subExpression': {'arguments': [{'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'Identifier'}],
                                                                                                                   'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                                                'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                                                 'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                  'memberName': 'send',
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                   'names': [],
                                                                                                                   'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                 'type': 'UnaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                                                   'type': 'Block'},
                                                      'condition': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                             'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                       'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                       'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                             'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                    'operator': '>=',
                                                                    'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                    'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'withdrawOkayish',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [{'isIndexed': False,
                                                            'isStateVar': False,
                                                            'name': 'amount',
                                                            'storageLocation': None,
                                                            'type': 'Parameter',
                                                            'typeName': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                         'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}}],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': None,
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'FalseBody': None,
                                                      'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                           'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                     'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                     'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                           'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                                                  'operator': '-=',
                                                                                                  'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                  'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'ExpressionStatement'},
                                                                                  {'FalseBody': None,
                                                                                   'TrueBody': {'statements': [';'],
                                                                                                'type': 'Block'},
                                                                                   'condition': {'isPrefix': True,
                                                                                                 'operator': '!',
                                                                                                 'subExpression': {'arguments': [],
                                                                                                                   'expression': {'arguments': [{'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'Identifier'}],
                                                                                                                                  'expression': {'expression': {'arguments': [{'number': '2500000',
                                                                                                                                                                               'subdenomination': None,
                                                                                                                                                                               'type': 'NumberLiteral'}],
                                                                                                                                                                'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                                                                                                             'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                                                                                                             'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                                              'memberName': 'call',
                                                                                                                                                                                              'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                               'memberName': 'gas',
                                                                                                                                                                               'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                'names': [],
                                                                                                                                                                'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                                                                 'memberName': 'value',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                  'names': [],
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                                   'names': [],
                                                                                                                   'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                 'type': 'UnaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                                                   'type': 'Block'},
                                                      'condition': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                             'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                       'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                       'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                             'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                    'operator': '>=',
                                                                    'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                    'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'withdrawBad2',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [{'isIndexed': False,
                                                            'isStateVar': False,
                                                            'name': 'amount',
                                                            'storageLocation': None,
                                                            'type': 'Parameter',
                                                            'typeName': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                         'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}}],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': None,
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'}],
               'type': 'ContractDefinition'}],
 'type': 'SourceUnit'}
```

I have found that it does not handle the throw keyword. Both if case block contains only ';'.
I am not able to find a way to resolve this issue. Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Created issue here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser/issues/11

Comment: Not a python guy here, but I did take a moment to pull in the grammar and run it against your input.  I can confirm that the ANTLR grammar used in that project does find the ```throw``` statement and includes it in it's parse tree.  So the problem will lie somewhere other than the ANTLR grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Still... not a Python programmer)

This took quite a bit of hacking around on my part just to pick up modifications.  (For example, on my system,  `scripts/antlr4.sh` (BTW, docs say `script/antlr4`, so... off to a great start.) doesn't execute properly)

That said, in the `solidity_antlr4` directory is a `parser.py` source file.

It is missing a `visitThrowStatement` method.

I added:

```py
    def visitThrowStatement(self,ctx):
        return Node(ctx=ctx,
                    type='ThrowStatement')
```

amongst the other `visits*` `def`s.

After moving my code to the site-packages (told ya... not a Python program, and definitely hacking around here, so not the right way to accomplish effecting this change I'm sure)

My output from running `python3 -m solidity_parser parse ./samples/so_example.sol > testParse.txt` (where `./samples/so_example.sol`  is your sample input) is:

```
{'children': [{'name': 'solidity',
               'type': 'PragmaDirective',
               'value': '^0.4.13'},
              {'baseContracts': [],
               'kind': 'contract',
               'name': 'someContract',
               'subNodes': [{'initialValue': None,
                             'type': 'StateVariableDeclaration',
                             'variables': [{'expression': None,
                                            'isDeclaredConst': False,
                                            'isIndexed': False,
                                            'isStateVar': True,
                                            'name': 'balances',
                                            'type': 'VariableDeclaration',
                                            'typeName': {'keyType': {'name': 'address',
                                                                     'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'},
                                                         'type': 'Mapping',
                                                         'valueType': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                       'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}},
                                            'visibility': 'default'}]},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                       'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                              'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                       'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                        'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                        'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                              'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                     'operator': '+=',
                                                                     'right': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                               'memberName': 'value',
                                                                               'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                     'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'ExpressionStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'deposit',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': 'payable',
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'FalseBody': None,
                                                      'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                           'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                     'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                     'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                           'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                                                  'operator': '-=',
                                                                                                  'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                  'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'ExpressionStatement'},
                                                                                  {'FalseBody': None,
                                                                                   'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'type': 'ThrowStatement'}],
                                                                                                'type': 'Block'},
                                                                                   'condition': {'isPrefix': True,
                                                                                                 'operator': '!',
                                                                                                 'subExpression': {'arguments': [{'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'Identifier'}],
                                                                                                                   'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                                                'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                                                 'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                  'memberName': 'send',
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                   'names': [],
                                                                                                                   'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                 'type': 'UnaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                                                   'type': 'Block'},
                                                      'condition': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                             'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                       'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                       'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                             'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                    'operator': '>=',
                                                                    'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                    'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'withdrawOkayish',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [{'isIndexed': False,
                                                            'isStateVar': False,
                                                            'name': 'amount',
                                                            'storageLocation': None,
                                                            'type': 'Parameter',
                                                            'typeName': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                         'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}}],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': None,
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'},
                            {'body': {'statements': [{'FalseBody': None,
                                                      'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'expression': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                           'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                    'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                     'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                     'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                           'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                                                  'operator': '-=',
                                                                                                  'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                  'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'ExpressionStatement'},
                                                                                  {'FalseBody': None,
                                                                                   'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'type': 'ThrowStatement'}],
                                                                                                'type': 'Block'},
                                                                                   'condition': {'isPrefix': True,
                                                                                                 'operator': '!',
                                                                                                 'subExpression': {'arguments': [],
                                                                                                                   'expression': {'arguments': [{'name': 'amount',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'Identifier'}],
                                                                                                                                  'expression': {'expression': {'arguments': [{'number': '2500000',
                                                                                                                                                                               'subdenomination': None,
                                                                                                                                                                               'type': 'NumberLiteral'}],
                                                                                                                                                                'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                                                                                                                                             'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                                                                                                                                             'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                                              'memberName': 'call',
                                                                                                                                                                                              'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                               'memberName': 'gas',
                                                                                                                                                                               'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                                                'names': [],
                                                                                                                                                                'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                                                                 'memberName': 'value',
                                                                                                                                                 'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                                                                                  'names': [],
                                                                                                                                  'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                                   'names': [],
                                                                                                                   'type': 'FunctionCall'},
                                                                                                 'type': 'UnaryOperation'},
                                                                                   'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                                                   'type': 'Block'},
                                                      'condition': {'left': {'base': {'name': 'balances',
                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                             'index': {'expression': {'name': 'msg',
                                                                                                      'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                                       'memberName': 'sender',
                                                                                       'type': 'MemberAccess'},
                                                                             'type': 'IndexAccess'},
                                                                    'operator': '>=',
                                                                    'right': {'name': 'amount',
                                                                              'type': 'Identifier'},
                                                                    'type': 'BinaryOperation'},
                                                      'type': 'IfStatement'}],
                                      'type': 'Block'},
                             'isConstructor': False,
                             'modifiers': [],
                             'name': 'withdrawBad2',
                             'parameters': {'parameters': [{'isIndexed': False,
                                                            'isStateVar': False,
                                                            'name': 'amount',
                                                            'storageLocation': None,
                                                            'type': 'Parameter',
                                                            'typeName': {'name': 'uint',
                                                                         'type': 'ElementaryTypeName'}}],
                                            'type': 'ParameterList'},
                             'returnParameters': [],
                             'stateMutability': None,
                             'type': 'FunctionDefinition',
                             'visibility': 'default'}],
               'type': 'ContractDefinition'}],
 'type': 'SourceUnit'}
```

relevant excerpt example:

```
 'TrueBody': {'statements': [{'type': 'ThrowStatement'}],
                                                                                                'type': 'Block'},
```

I don't even know if this is the right content, but it does demonstrate that the solution will be to rebuild with a `visitThrowStatement` implemented.

(It's absence, would make me suspect other visitor methods may also be missing.)